# Нужна ли в этом случае запятая?

Tags: запятые

"Ричардса всякий знает где найти". Нужна ли здесь запятая?

Answer (score 3):

Интересный пример. Здесь нужна запятая перед словом "где". Это сложноподчиненное предложение, разговорный стиль речи, главное предложение — внутри придаточного. После "Ричардса" запятая не нужна. Источник — справочник Розенталя 1999 г.

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/49.htm

Comment: *После "Ричардса" запятая не нужна.* Ещё не хватало, чтобы она нужна.

Comment: Да, конечно) подправил ответ.

Comment: *чтобы она **была** нужна. Вы не поняли: после "Ричардса" ставить запятую просто абсурдно, поэтому я бы вообще не стал такое рассматривать на вашем месте.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Это не абсурдно. Убираем "*где найти*", и получается совсем другой смысл: *Ричардса всякий знает*. Придаточное: *Ричардса где найти*, а "*всякий знает*" разделяет его.

Comment: @oleedd и тёзка: да, я понял ход мысли. Логично.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой "чтобы она нужна" — вы тут "была" пропустили или так можно сказать?

Comment: @oleedd: да конечно! Я ж потом поправился) Случайно забыл.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что "всякий знает" - здесь главное по смыслу предложение, а "где найти Ричардса" - придаточное?

Comment: @Евгений Вы правильно понимаете. По ссылке у Розенталя это §107, примечание 1 (главное внутри придаточного, разговорный стиль, единственная запятая после главного).

Comment: Да, действительно... Спасибо большое.